# Did Prophets before Muhammed (PBUH) perform Prayers?

Tags: salat, prophets

How did earlier prophets before Muhammed (PBUH) worship Allah ? Was there *Salah* during the period of Adam(PBUH), was it  mandatory to offer Prayers for them ?

Comment: I know Jews perform Prayers and it's mandatory for them.

Answer (score 3):

Of course it was, see the Qura'n:

> Our Lord, I have settled some of my descendants in an uncultivated valley near Your sacred House, our Lord, that they may establish **prayer**. So make hearts among the people incline toward them and provide for them from the fruits that they might be grateful.[14:37](http://tanzil.net/#14:37)

> My Lord, make me an establisher of **prayer**, and [many] from my descendants. Our Lord, and accept my supplication. [[14:40]](http://tanzil.net/#14:40)

> And He has made me blessed wherever I am and has enjoined upon me **prayer** and zakah as long as I remain alive [[19:31]](http://tanzil.net/#19:31)

> So the angels called him while he was standing in **prayer** in the chamber, "Indeed, Allah gives you good tidings of John, confirming a word from Allah and [who will be] honorable, abstaining [from women], and a prophet from among the righteous." [3:39](http://tanzil.net/#3:39)

and many more.

In addition, the prayer did look like ours:

> And [mention] when We made the House a place of return for the people and [a place of] security. And take, [O believers], from the standing place of Abraham a place of **prayer**. And We charged Abraham and Ishmael, [saying], "Purify My House for those who perform Tawaf and those who are staying [there] for worship and those who **bow and prostrate** [in **prayer**]." [2:125](http://tanzil.net/#2:125)

> O Mary, be devoutly obedient to your Lord and **prostrate and bow** with those who bow [in **prayer**]."[3:43](http://tanzil.net/#3:43)

From these verses we know that the prayers did contain bowing and prostrating. But we don't know exactly how it was.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, They Did Offer Prayers, But not necessarily as Muhammed (PBUH) taught us. They did `Sujud`. Ibrahim (PBUH) and Ismail (PBUH) had built `KABAH` and offerred Prayer to God.

Comment: Welcome to islam-stackexchange, it would be better if you provided reference for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

To the guy who has commented that we can worship in any form.. See brother if that point is valid or not, That is a different thing..

We are from the Ummah of Prophet Muhammad (PBUH).. and He (PBUH) instructed us to offer salat like he (PBUH) used to.

And Nimaaz/Salat is the second pillar of Islam...

Please dont try to create differences or deviate people here.. We have to offer prayer/salat and it is super Important.

There are many other forms of worship also like zikr etc but those types of worship cannot replace Nimaaz/Salat.. Nimaaz/Salat is Must!

And yeah how to offer Nimaaz/Salaat, When to offer it? We have hadeeth... Go check them...You will get your answers.

It is not necessary that how to offer prayer should be mentioned in Quran. If it is not specifically mentioned in Quran. Hadeeth are there.

Answer (score -1):

yes all the prophets before muhammad s.a.w. off course PRAYED to god. but the method and techniques were not thought to us how did they exactly pray. but ancient sources said that prophets before muhammad s.a.w. like jesus as., moses as., noah as., adam as., abraham as., etc "PROSTRATED" to god in a way to pray/worship god. it proves that the movement to bow and prostrate like how we do now in salah has ancient roots that god appointed every prophet to prostrate to him. and the main purpose of the worship/ibadah which u can say "salat" is exactly to show servitude to allah swt which was done by all the prophets.

Answer (score -4):

there is no specific method for worshipping... all  sources ancient or not is tampered with. it cannot be trusted. men use to worship men bowing and prostrating to them...others kneeled... others went flat on their stomachs... the Quran states.... you can WORSHIP ME in ANY FORM. Go do some homework. after all millions of MUSLIMS have never ever read the Quran... his own book from start to finish to try to comprehend what is says or has to offer... including "PRACTISING MUSLIMS".

Comment: This does not answer the question. Also "the Quran states.... you can WORSHIP ME in ANY FORM" should be supported with evidence.

Comment: Consider providing evidences to support your claims and see [answer].