# Who first read the Salah?

Tags: salat, prophet-muhammad

Many of my relatives told me that prophet muhammad told the people to offer salah .
But , I wonder if Jesus , Noah, Abraham, Adam didn't they read Salah , the must have done it then why do we say Prophet Muhammad is the founder of Salah and as well as the founder of Islam ?

Comment: Related post https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/39804/in-which-direction-did-noah-and-adam-pray

Comment: What is your source — other than your family — that Muslims say that the Prophet ﷺ was the founder of Islam or the founder of the prayers? This is not the Islamic belief at all.

Comment: duplicate of https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16717/did-prophets-before-muhammed-pbuh-perform-prayers

Answer (score 1):

Salah was already enjoined on [Musa](https://legacy.quran.com/10/87) and ['Isa](https://legacy.quran.com/19/31) along with the [Children of Israel](https://legacy.quran.com/2/83). Muhammad told people to offer salah according to the timings and method that was enjoined upon him.

```
لِكُلٍّ جَعَلْنَا مِنكُمْ شِرْعَةً وَمِنْهَاجًا

To each of you We prescribed a law and a method.

Surat Al-Maidah, 48
```